# Reformat array in react

Tags: react-native

Using react I'm looking for a way to transform this Json

```
[
   {
      "date":"2019-01-01",
      "a":4000,
      "f":251,
      "h":0.15,
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-01-02",
      "a":878,
      "f":987,
      "h":0.87,
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-01-03",
      "a":1287,
      "f":412,
      "h":0.56,
   }
]
```

Into something like this :

```
{
    date: [
        '2019-01-01',
        '2019-01-02',
        '2019-01-03'
    ],
    a: [
        4000,
        878,
        1287
    ]
};
```

But using Array.forEach, It doesn't works because I can't create named keys.

So far here's what I have (tempData is the Json I receive):

```
let newData = [];
tempData.forEach((element,i) => {
    newData['date'][i] = element.date;
    newData['a'][i] = element.i;
});
```

I can't figure out how to make a new array like I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have specified `newData` as an array but you are looking to use it like an object. Also there are no keys with arrays defined in the object, so you need to define them first of all before trying to insert into them.

If you change you declaration to

`let newData = { data: [], a: [] }`

also you need to fix the line

`newData['a'][i] = element.i;`

it should be

`newData['a'][i] = element.a;`

it should work.

```js
let tempData = [
  {
    "date":"2019-01-01",
    "a":4000,
    "f":251,
    "h":0.15,
  },
  {
    "date":"2019-01-02",
    "a":878,
    "f":987,
    "h":0.87,
  },
  {
    "date":"2019-01-03",
    "a":1287,
    "f":412,
    "h":0.56,
  }
];

let newData = { date: [], a: []};
tempData.forEach((element,i) => {
    newData['date'][i] = element.date;
    newData['a'][i] = element.a;
});

console.log(newData)
```

If you want you can also dynamically create the keys in the object, something similar to this.

```js
let tempData = [
  {
    "date":"2019-01-01",
    "a":4000,
    "f":251,
    "h":0.15,
  },
  {
    "date":"2019-01-02",
    "a":878,
    "f":987,
    "h":0.87,
  },
  {
    "date":"2019-01-03",
    "a":1287,
    "f":412,
    "h":0.56,
  }
];

let newData = { };
let keys = Object.keys(tempData[0])
keys.forEach(key => {
  newData[key] = []
})

tempData.forEach((element,i) => {
    Object.keys(element).forEach( key => {
      newData[key].push(element[key])
    })
});

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, that's it !
And I know about the fix on the line, it was a test on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need React for this. You should be able to do this with plain JavaScript. The [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on the `Array` object will help. Here's one way to do it:

```
let newData = {};
let dates = newData.map(data => data.date); // "dates" is now an array
let aValues = newData.map(data => data.a); // "aValues" is now an array
newData.date = dates;
newDate.a = aValues;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I mentionned react if anybody have a "secret" function of react that's usefull. Otherwise your method is not suitable for me because my example was shrink for the question, but I can't do 100 times a map on the same array it's too much.

Comment: If you wanna use map function, then something like `const newData = {
  date: array.map(item => item.date),
  a: array.map(item => item.a)
}` is cleaner